# A confusing psychological thriller movie with two leading actresses, among one is a Hollywood actress or a wannabe actress

Tags: identify-this-movie, thriller, american-cinema

I have only a vague description about this 90s or 2000s movie. I am sure the movie plot itself was so confusing.

I think there are two female lead characters and the film is happening in Hollywood.

One is a wannabe actress and the other one is an established actress (not sure).

In the beginning of the film, one of the lead actresses met with an accident and got the help of the other. I think she lost her memory too.

The two actresses seems to be in love with each other and one becomes missing. The other looks for her and finds her decomposing dead body and recollected that she killed her. Also she had some mental problem and she was not who she assumed she was. She switched her character with the other actress. She killed herself because she indicated breaking up with her.

I am sure it was a critically well acclaimed movie and that was the reason I watched that 4-5 years ago.

Comment: *I am sure the movie plot itself was so confusing.* - Understatement of the century :) It's an amazing film that *definitely* requires some deciphering.

Comment: Haha, +1 for writing  a better, clearer, more coherent description of Mulholland Drive than I could have managed immediately after watching it!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sounds like David Lynch's [Mulholland Dr.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mulholland_Drive_(film)) from 2001.

> Mulholland Drive (stylized onscreen as Mulholland Dr.) is a 2001 American neo-noir mystery film written and directed by David Lynch and starring Naomi Watts, Laura Harring, and Justin Theroux. It tells the story of an aspiring actress named Betty Elms (Watts), newly arrived in Los Angeles, California, who meets and befriends an amnesic woman (Harring) hiding in an apartment that belongs to Elms's aunt. The story includes several other seemingly unrelated vignettes that eventually connect in various ways, as well as some surreal and darkly comic scenes and images that relate to the cryptic narrative.

The rest of the plot unfolds as you've described. And don't feel bad about being confused - this is quite intentional; the complex plot spawned many theories trying to explain it. Here's the trailer: